# Unix Popen.communicate not able to gzip large file

Tags: python, unix, subprocess, gzip, popen

I need to gzip files of size more than 10 GB using python on top of shell commands and hence decided to use subprocess Popen.

Here is my code:

```
outputdir = '/mnt/json/output/'
inp_cmd='gzip -r ' + outputdir

pipe = Popen(["bash"], stdout =PIPE,stdin=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)
cmd = bytes(inp_cmd.encode('utf8'))
stdout_data,stderr_data = pipe.communicate(input=cmd)
```

It is not gzip-ing the files within output directory.
Any way out?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use  subprocess.call() instead of subprocess.communicate().

call() waits till the command is executed completely while in Popen(), one has to extrinsically use wait() method for the execution to finish.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried it like this:

```
output_dir = "/mnt/json/output/"

cmd = "gzip -r {}".format(output_dir)

proc = subprocess.Popen(
    cmd,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    shell=True,
)

out, err = proc.communicate()
```

Comment: What is the difference between the code that I have posted and the one that you have given?  There is not an evident change.

Comment: My answer actually passes the command (`cmd`) to `Popen` as the first parameter. It also uses `shell=True`. You should read the [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) docs and take a look at the [security considerations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations).

Comment: Tried, not working.. It has something to do with wait or timeout, I guess.

Comment: Do you get a `TimeoutExpired` exception raised? If not it's probably not that. This code works and will gzip all the files in a directory. Have you tried running this in a python shell?

Comment: Yes @Alex, I have run it. The command gets executed but without any result.

Comment: Then what happens when you run the gzip command from a normal shell? What is the value of `stderr`?